# calling Axios api with ${item} in the url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I am unable to call axios on Vuetify because the URL has backticks and `${}` in it.  I guess I am suppose to make it JSON, so I have tried, but it is not working. Can you explain this to me?

Below is my code. When I push the `Search` button, the console says:

> ```
> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: 'ReferenceError: term is not defined'
> ```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app >
    <v-form >
      <v-row class="app">
        <v-col class="text-center" cols="12" sm="4">
             <v-text-field
              placeholder="Find Book"
            ></v-text-field>
          <div class="my-2">
            <v-btn v-on:click="getBooks" large color="primary">Search</v-btn>
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      </v-form>
  </v-app>
  <!-- You may use this container for your listing -->
  <div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
  components: {},
  data(){
    return{
      books: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getBooks: function() {
      const apiUrl = `https://goodreads-server-express--dotdash.repl.co/search/${term}`;
      const obj = JSON.parse(apiUrl)
 
      axios.get("obj")
        .then(function (resp) {
        this.books = resp.data
        console.log(this.books)
      })
    },
  }    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (the backticked string) supports placeholders (the `${term}` part), which can contain expressions, or in this case, a variable. `${term}` throws an error because there is no variable named "term" in the current scope.

You also don't need to use `JSON.parse()` on `apiUrl`, since `apiUrl` is not JSON. Instead, pass `apiUrl` directly to `axios.get()`:

```js
const term = 'Moby Dick';
const apiUrl = `https://goodreads-server-express--dotdash.repl.co/search/${term}`;
axios.get(apiUrl).then(...)
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    books: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    getBooks() {
      const term = 'Moby Dick'
      const apiUrl = `https://goodreads-server-express--dotdash.repl.co/search/${term}`
      axios.get(apiUrl).then(resp => {
        this.books = resp.data
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.20.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="getBooks">Get books</button>
  <pre>{{ books }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Quick question.. so if I need the input to come to the term .. then I can add search: ' ' in the data() and vmodel the <v-text-field> and change your const term to const term = this.search